# How to Fix Format String bug

Tags: unhandled-exception, format-string

A practical example of the bug "in action" is the following:

- Attacker sends: `/hello-%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x`
- Server logs:

> [17:17:28] Consoled: 'hello-082aeefc.00000131.0061b64c.00000011' run
>   from 192.168.0.3:32768

**Update**:
The bug is caused by the logging function NetManager_LogMessage which
takes the text to dump, adds a timestamp (using snprintf) and then
passes the whole string to the function `File_printf` without the needed
format argument (`%s`) and how to fix it?

What i have done wrong and why its happening?

I debug in IDA and when i test to Crash the Server. It returns the Memory Invalid access error.

[image]

Comment: Escape everything you're sending to your log method. There's no huge difference from the URL to any other form-data a user puts into some inputs. All should be considered dangerous and properly escaped before using it in any mechanism like building (sql)queries, logging it, storing it in a database...

Comment: Yes i agree with you. but this Process is Live. i am patching it live with IDA and i don't know how to escape with %% and i am not sure this game is written n C or not. The developers are not replying to my email because they are no longer supported to this game. IGI 2 Covert Strike.

Comment: Using a big nickname is possible to crash the server due the access to
an invalid memory zone.
The instruction executed is "cmp [EAX], 00000000" where EAX contains 4
of the bytes in the nickname.